# Пытаюсь запустить nginx на сервере, с чем связана моя ошибка?

Tags: nginx

Пытаюсь запустить nginx на сервере, с чем связана моя ошибка?

Если нужна будет доп. информация быстро предоставлю.
КОНФИГ

```js
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

```js
nginx.service - nginx - high performance web server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/nginx.service.d
             └─nofile.conf
     Active: failed (Result: signal) since Tue 2023-11-07 18:58:15 MSK; 16min ago
       Docs: https://nginx.org/en/docs/
    Process: 270181 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 270192 (code=killed, signal=KILL)

Nov 07 18:35:02 jekil2.fvds.ru systemd[1]: Starting nginx - high performance web server...
Nov 07 18:35:02 jekil2.fvds.ru systemd[1]: nginx.service: Can't open PID file /run/nginx.pid (yet?) after start: Operation not permitted
Nov 07 18:35:02 jekil2.fvds.ru systemd[1]: Started nginx - high performance web server.
```

Comment: Ошибки публикуйте текстом, а не картинками.

Comment: хорошо, спасибо за замечание, учту!)

Comment: killed? Читайте в логах что происходило в момент килла